# Apache rewrite rule to external address with proxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-proxy

I need to rewrite https://test.domain.com to http://172.23.190.20/test with this rule:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$      http://172.23.190.20:80/test [P]`

According to this page it should work:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=d7afc0ac-8980-54b2-9552-7b3ddf70b002

But it redirects me to https://test.domain.com/test/ with redirection loop message.
How to make it work?

Comment: If it redirects then `mod_proxy` is not correctly setup.

Comment: ok, what to check then?